# Outlook 2013 send to OneNote2013 removing image

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I use the "Send to OneNote" addin for Outlook 2013 to archive and organize emails. If my Outlook message contains images, they get stripped out when imported into OneNote. After extensive googling I can't find any setting that will automatically pull the images into OneNote. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which mail format was the email sent to you in? Apparently images embedded in RTF emails won't be transferred. [source](http://www.textndata.com/forums/send-onenote-button-does-not-375904.html) [source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/embedded-images-from-rtf-emails-outlook-2010-sent/2a84ebc3-e1b0-4ba6-83d9-f841e0d26d44?page=1)

Comment: Thanks...looks like it was RTF. As a workaround I downloaded one note gem to paste rich text.

http://www.onenotegem.com/document/paste-rich-text-into-onenote-without-loses-formatting

Comment: Well if it worked for you, perhaps write up an answer covering why, where to get it and how to use it (you're encouraged to answer your own questions).